# Combining pandas DataFrames with different row count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have started developing some scripts to manipulate and plot data. I am not very experienced in using pandas with python.

The problem is described below. I have a DataFrame `time` with dates:

```
     Date
0   Jul-03      
1   Jul-04
2   Jul-05
3   Jul-06
4   Jul-07
5   Jul-08
6   Jul-09
```

And then I have two other DataFrames, `data1` and `data2`:

```
(data1)
     Date      Count
0   Jul-05      20
1   Jul-06      10
```

```
(data2)
     Date      Count
0   Jul-09      36
```

My goal is to get a DataFrame shown below in order to plot the results. As you can see, I need zeroes when there is no corresponding dates from `data1` and `data2` with respect to the `time` DataFrame.

```
     Date      data1      data2
0   Jul-03       0          0
1   Jul-04       0          0
2   Jul-05       20         0
3   Jul-06       10         0
4   Jul-07       0          0
5   Jul-08       0          0
6   Jul-09       0         36
```

I tried many things - have been fighting for 1 day but still no progress :). Hopefully, you can help!

Kind regards

Comment: In SQL, you'd handle this with joins. As it turns out, Pandas has a similar functionality for joining data frames. I'd recommend looking into that :)

Comment: What did you tried so far ? have you searched for pandas documentation ? it contains plenty of example and articles on how to manipulate data, and I'm rather sure that your problem is somewhat described there. Show your efforts first: documentation, lnks, code, other SO questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the other said: Go check the Doc on the internet !

Anyway here is a way to solve your problem:

## 1-  Set the Dataframes

```py
In [1]:
import pandas as pd

columns = ['Date']
data = ['Jul-03'
    ,'Jul-04'
    ,'Jul-05'
    ,'Jul-06'
    ,'Jul-07'
    ,'Jul-08'
    ,'Jul-09']

time = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = columns)

columns = ['Date', 'Count']
data = [
        ['Jul-05', 20],
        ['Jul-06', 10]
       ]
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

data2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Jul-09', 36]], columns=columns)
```

## 2- Merge the Dataframes

```py
In [2]:
df_list = [data1, data2]
iterator = 0
for df in df_list:
    iterator += 1
    column_name = 'data' + str(iterator)
    time = time.merge(df, how='left', left_on='Date', right_on='Date').fillna(0).rename(columns={'Count':column_name})
time
 
Out [2]:
    Date    data1   data2
0   Jul-03  0.0     0.0
1   Jul-04  0.0     0.0
2   Jul-05  20.0    0.0
3   Jul-06  10.0    0.0
4   Jul-07  0.0     0.0
5   Jul-08  0.0     0.0
6   Jul-09  0.0     36.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did not use for loop because ```data1```, ```data2```, ```data3``` and so on would have different names in my case. But your response shows very clearly how ```merge``` can be used with ```fillna```, which worked brilliant for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The row alignment will work, if "Date" is set as index.

```
df_rslt= df_time.set_index("Date")

df_rslt["data1"]= df_data1.set_index("Date")["Count"]
df_rslt["data2"]= df_data2.set_index("Date")["Count"]

df_rslt.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```